# bash what means quotes inside asterisk *"str"*

Tags: bash

I have an example

```
o="o" 
if [[ *"aoei"* == $o ]]; then echo 5; fi;
```

What means asterisk in this example?

p.s. is order important? `if [[ *"o"* == $o ]]` vs `if [[ $o == *"o"* ]]`

Comment: @FrankThomas
can you please tell a little bit more about wildcards in this sample? I'm knowing about wildcards (`echo *`, `ls *.txt`). You can write it like an answer, I will accept it probably

Comment: @FrankThomas Also for me by some reason the order has a mean `david@david-ThinkPad-E480:/$ if [[ *"о"* == $t ]]; then echo 5; fi;
david@david-ThinkPad-E480:/$ if [[ $t == *"о"* ]]; then echo 5; fi;
5
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order is crucial. As [documented for the `[[` conditional construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b), the `==` operator is a *pattern matching* operator where the *right-hand* side is a [glob pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) (aka "wildcard").

- `[[ *"o"* == $o ]]` tests if the literal string `*o*` matches the pattern contained in the variable `$o`
- `[[ $o == *"o"* ]]` tests if the string contained in the variable `$o` matches the pattern `*o*` (i.e. if the contents of $o **contains** an `o`)

Note that the pattern `*"aoei"*` means: zero or more of any character, followed by the exact sequence `aoei`, followed by zero or more of any character. Perhaps you intended the pattern `*[aoei]*` which means: contains an `a` or an `o` or an `e` or an `i`.

Demonstrating:

```bsh
$ o="o"
$ if [[ *"aoei"* == $o ]]; then echo 5; fi;     # no output
$ if [[ $o == *"aoei"* ]]; then echo 5; fi;     # no output

$ o="AaoeiBC"
$ if [[ *"aoei"* == $o ]]; then echo 5; fi;     # no output
$ if [[ $o == *"aoei"* ]]; then echo 5; fi;
5

$ o="o"
$ if [[ *[aoei]* == $o ]]; then echo 5; fi;     # no output
$ if [[ $o == *[aoei]* ]]; then echo 5; fi;
5
```

Comment: Note that this answer describes how `[[ ]]` conditional expressions work. A `[ ]` test is significantly different from this. `[ ]` cannot do wildcard pattern matching, and if you try the results tend to be ... unfortunate. Also, in `[ ]`, `==` is not a standard operator; you should use `=` instead (and put double-quotes around variable references, e.g. `[ "$o" = foo ]` instead of `[ $o = foo ]`).